# R - How to perform arithmetic operations on some but not all variables over rows, omitting NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data.frame:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(0,1,NA,3,4)
c <- c(9,10,11,NA,13)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I managed to write a custom function which I can use to sum certain variables over rows, while ignoring NAs (in this case, I sum over all variables, but imagine a big data.frame where I only need to add up a few variables):

```
sum.df.na.rm <- function(x) {
    rowSums(df[,x], na.rm = TRUE)
}

df$d <- sum.df.na.rm(c("a","b","c"))

> df
  a  b  c  d
  1  0  9 10
  2  1 10 13
  3 NA 11 14
  4  3 NA  7
  5  4 13 22
```

Now suppose I want to substract b from a, and add c, while still ignoring NAs. I can do:

```
df$bneg <- df$b * (-1)
df$e <- sum.df.na.rm(c("a","bneg","c"))

> df
  a  b  c  d bneg  e
  1  0  9 10    0 10
  2  1 10 13   -1 11
  3 NA 11 14   NA 14
  4  3 NA  7   -3  1
  5  4 13 22   -4 14
```

But having to multiply b by (-1) to have it substracted in the `sum.df.na.rm` function seems very inefficient to me.

How would you do this without the use of the intermediate variable *bneg*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own operators:

```
> `%+%` <- function(e1, e2) {e1[is.na(e1)] <- 0; e2[is.na(e2)] <- 0; return(e1 + e2)}
> `%-%` <- function(e1, e2) {e1[is.na(e1)] <- 0; e2[is.na(e2)] <- 0; return(e1 - e2)}
> within(df, e <- a %-% b %+% c)
  a  b  c  e
1 1  0  9 10
2 2  1 10 11
3 3 NA 11 14
4 4  3 NA  1
5 5  4 13 14
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do that!
Could you explain what the elements of the operator definitions mean? 
To me it seems that e1 is referring to the left division sign, and e2 to the right division sign, and in executing the operators the divisions signs kind of *pull in* the next object to the left and right and take them as e1 and e2?

Comment: Type ``+`` (surrounded by backticks) into your console to see that `+` is just a function. These modifications of `+` and `-` are just modeled after their original function definitions using [special operator notation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Special-operators).

Comment: Thanks! Well I see that ``+`` is `function(e1, e2) .Primitive("+")` which doesn't really tell me how you used the part in curly brackets to define the new operator. I see that *e1* and *e2* are set to 0 if they are missing, but where does the operator get *e1* and *e2* from and what does the `return()` do?

Comment: @iraserd Those are the function's formal arguments, which is to say it's all just basic function definition stuff. Take a look at [the relevant documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Functions).